# My First problem on pyspark dataframe. getting [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified Error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
        
spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("SparkByExamples.com").getOrCreate();
    
data2 = [(1, 'Smith', 2018, 10, 'M', 3000), (2, 'Rose', 2010, 20, 'F', 4000), (3, 'Williams', 
        2010, 10, 'M', 1000),(4, 'Jones', 2005, 10, 'M', 2000), (5, 'Brown', 2010, 40, 'F', 
        3200)]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("Emp_id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Emp_name", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Year joined", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("Emp_dep_id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Salary", IntegerType(), True)
    ])

df_emp = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=schema)
df_emp.show()
```

Getting Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\228091\PycharmProjects\Project1\task2.py", line 9, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("SparkByExamples.com").getOrCreate();
  File "C:\spark1\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
  File "C:\spark1\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 384, in getOrCreate
  File "C:\spark1\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 144, in __init__
  File "C:\spark1\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 331, in _ensure_initialized
  File "C:\spark1\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 101, in launch_gateway
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: A bit late but it would seem that you may not have your winutils set-up properly.  I ran your code and it worked.  Try adding, above your other imports: import os and os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = r"C:\winutils" (or wherever you put the winutils).